# Fail getting png from svg using canvg

Tags: javascript, svg, png, canvg

I am using canvg.js to export a svg element to png image using cavas toDataUrl() but the resulting image is not correct

I read another related post and they say that there is an error in canvg parsing text nodes, but it doesn't show rectangles of the legend also.

The initial svg image is

[svg chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRiK6.png)

The resulting base64 image is

[resulting base64 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rry9.png)

The svg element is

```html
<g transform="translate(3,3)">
            <g transform="translate(418.9943664965987,0)">
                <g clip-path="url(#nx)">
                    <clipPath id="nx">
                        <rect x="5" y="5" width="273.359375" height="235"></rect>
                    </clipPath>
                    <g transform="translate(5,5)">
                        <g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(31,119,180)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(31,119,180)" stroke="rgb(31,119,180)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="20" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,20)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(255,127,14)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(255,127,14)" stroke="rgb(255,127,14)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="40" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,40)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(44,160,44)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(44,160,44)" stroke="rgb(44,160,44)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Classic Cars, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="60" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,60)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(214,39,40)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(214,39,40)" stroke="rgb(214,39,40)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Classic Cars, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="80" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,80)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(148,103,189)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(148,103,189)" stroke="rgb(148,103,189)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Motorcycles, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="100" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,100)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(140,86,75)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(140,86,75)" stroke="rgb(140,86,75)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Motorcycles, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="120" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,120)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(227,119,194)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(227,119,194)" stroke="rgb(227,119,194)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Planes, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="140" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,140)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(127,127,127)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(127,127,127)" stroke="rgb(127,127,127)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Planes, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="160" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,160)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(188,189,34)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(188,189,34)" stroke="rgb(188,189,34)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Ships, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="180" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,180)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(23,190,207)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(23,190,207)" stroke="rgb(23,190,207)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Ships, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="200" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,200)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(31,119,180)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(31,119,180)" stroke="rgb(31,119,180)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Trains, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="220" width="122.40625" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,220)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(255,127,14)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(255,127,14)" stroke="rgb(255,127,14)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Trains, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                        <g transform="translate(127.40625,0)">
                            <rect cursor="pointer" width="145.953125" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(44,160,44)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(44,160,44)" stroke="rgb(44,160,44)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Trucks and Buses, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="20" width="145.953125" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,20)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(214,39,40)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(214,39,40)" stroke="rgb(214,39,40)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Trucks and Buses, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="40" width="145.953125" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,40)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(148,103,189)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(148,103,189)" stroke="rgb(148,103,189)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Vintage Cars, Quantity
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <rect cursor="pointer" y="60" width="145.953125" height="15" fill="rgb(200,200,200)"
                                  fill-opacity="0.0001"></rect>
                            <g transform="translate(0,60)">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <line shape-rendering="crispEdges" cursor="pointer" x1="0" y1="7.5" x2="15"
                                              y2="7.5" stroke="rgb(140,86,75)" stroke-width="1"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g>
                                        <path cursor="pointer" fill="rgb(140,86,75)" stroke="rgb(140,86,75)"
                                              transform="translate(7.5,7.5)"
                                              d="M-3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417L3.872983346207417,-3.872983346207417 3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417 -3.872983346207417,3.872983346207417Z"></path>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <text pointer-events="none" x="2" dy=".35em" transform="translate(15,7.5)"
                                          fill="rgb(0,0,0)">Vintage Cars, Sales
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
```

As you can see the legend part is not ok. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the last version of canvg the problem is solved. Best Regards.